# Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?

Tags: git, githooks

We'd like to make a few basic hook scripts that we can all share -- for things like pre-formatting commit messages.  Git has hook scripts for that that are normally stored under `<project>/.git/hooks/`.  However, those scripts are not propagated when people do a clone and they are not version controlled.

Is there a good way to help everyone get the right hook scripts?  Can I just make those hook scripts point to version controlled scripts in my repo?

Comment: A good question.  I only wish there was a better answer (with no complaints to @mipadi, I just wish git had a way to do this in a more automatic way -- even if only with an option specified to git clone.)

Comment: I agree, @lindes! But perhaps restricting this sharing of hooks in intentional? Things would get messy for Windows users, I suppose.

Comment: @kristianlm: There are all sorts of reasons it could be messy at times... and also times when it's nice to have it there.  I just wish there was some option or something that would copy the hooks.  I guess I'll just have to check out the git-core code sometime, and make a patch.  :)  (Or hope that someone else does...  or live with the workaround in [mipadi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/427269/313756), or whatever.)

Comment: [`pre-commit`](https://github.com/observing/pre-commit) makes this easy for pre-commit hooks. Doesn't answer the OP's question about managing any arbitrary git hook, but pre-commit hooks are probably the most frequently used for code quality purposes.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Theoretically, you could create a `hooks` directory (or whatever name you prefer) in your project directory with all the scripts, and then symlink them in `.git/hooks`. Of course, each person who cloned the repo would have to set up these symlinks (although you could get really fancy and have a deploy script that the cloner could run to set them up semi-automatically).

To do the symlink on *nix, all you need to do is:

```bash
root="$(pwd)"
ln -s "$root/hooks" "$root/.git/hooks"
```

use `ln -sf` if you're ready to overwrite what's in `.git/hooks`

Comment: this was non-trivial, so i'm including a link as to how to symlink properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592838/symbolic-link-to-a-hook-in-git

Comment: git version 2.9 now has a config option for `core.hooksPath` to set up a file outside of .git  to link to the hooks folder.

Answer (score 352):

In [Git 2.9](https://github.com/blog/2188-git-2-9-has-been-released), the 
configuration option [`core.hooksPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) specifies a custom hooks directory.

Move your hooks to a `hooks` tracked directory in your repository. Then, configure *each instance* of the repository to use the tracked `hooks` instead of `$GIT_DIR/hooks`:

```
git config core.hooksPath hooks
```

In general, the path may be absolute, or relative to the directory where the hooks are run (usually the working tree root; see DESCRIPTION section of [`man githooks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)).

Comment: ... and the hooks directory to point to can be s separate hooks repository ;)

Comment: Well, is this config parameter auto set when you do a git clone?

Comment: As a rule git config variables can't be set by the repository you are cloning.  I think this is to prevent the execution of arbitrary code.  git config controls the execution of code through hooks, the user name on commit messages, and other important functions.

Comment: What if someone in the team does a git checkout to another branch? They have to include it in every branch..

Comment: That‘s true. On the other hand, if you update the hooks in newer commits, cloned repos will automatically get them when working on branches built on top of that commit. Both ways have their up- and downsides.

Comment: You can add `--global` to the command, which will change the `~/.gitconfig` file and make the change system-wide rather than per-repo.

Comment: ..unless you're using Bitbucket Server, because this: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10609

Comment: See https://www.viget.com/articles/two-ways-to-share-git-hooks-with-your-team/ for a great article on sharing git hooks

Comment: works perfect with this maven hook https://gist.github.com/hdznrrd/a457246d5bac99a1788cc81ea411fc04

Comment: It's real confusing to see version `Git 2.9` when `git-scm` is actually in version `2.41.0` at the time of writing this. I would recommend updating that language to be more explicit. That 2.9 is for GitHub only.

Comment: It requires that `core.hooksPath` be set globally or locally. I don't want to relying on my colleagues' goodwill to make side tasks in order to set git hooks up. This is error-prone and ineffective.

Answer (score 56):

For [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) users a simple solution is to update **package.json** with

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  ......
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "git config core.hooksPath hooks",
```

The *preinstall* will run before

> npm install

and redirects Git to look for hooks inside the **.\hooks** (or whatever name you choose) directory. This directory should mimic **.\.git\hooks** in terms of file name (minus the .sample) and structure.

Imagine [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) and other build tools will have an equivalent to *preinstall*.

It should also work across all platforms.

If you need any more information, see *[Two ways to share Git hooks with your team](https://www.viget.com/articles/two-ways-to-share-git-hooks-with-your-team/)*.

Comment: Keep in mind that `core.hooksPath` is only available on `git` versions `>= 2.9` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338979/8469219)

Answer (score 17):

If your project is a JavaScript project and you use `npm` as the package manager, you can use [shared-git-hooks](https://github.com/kilianc/shared-git-hooks) to enforce Git hooks on `npm install`.

Full disclosure: I wrote this package

Comment: Warning - does not support Windows (unless it's run as admin in git bash). Simple solution is to add "preinstall": "git config core.hooksPath hooks" as a script in package.json. i.e. Where hooks is a folder containing your git scripts.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to merge several answers into one. Assuming you are in your `project/` directory:

## Setup your custom hooks

1. Create `.githooks` directory and place your hooks in it. (See `.git/hooks` for examples)
2. Create a `.gitconfig` file that points the directory [¹](https://www.viget.com/articles/two-ways-to-share-git-hooks-with-your-team/):

   ```
   git config -f .gitconfig core.hooksPath .githooks
   ```
3. Create the following rule in your `Makefile`: [²](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/1952991)

   ```
   enable-git-hooks:
       git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig
       $(warning REMEMBER, YOU MUST HAVE REVIEWED THE CUSTOM HOOKS!)
   ```

## Enable your custom hooks

Every developer should [explicitly enable these custom hooks after reviewing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329621/how-to-store-a-git-config-as-part-of-the-repository#comment26906692_18330114). Add a directive to your README, something like that:

> Enable custom hooks AFTER REVIEWING them by `make enable-git-hooks`.

Comment: What do you mean with `Makefile`? This question is language agnostic.

Comment: One could argue that Makefile is language agnostic.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the modern programming languages, or rather their build tools, support plugins to manage Git hooks. That means all you need to do is configure your *package.json*, *pom.xml*, etc. files, and anyone in your team will have no option but to comply unless they change the build file.

The plugin will add content to .git directory for you.

**Examples:**

*[Git Build Hook Maven Plugin](https://github.com/rudikershaw/git-build-hook)*

*[githook-maven-plugin](https://github.com/olukyrich/githook-maven-plugin)*

*[git-hooks-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-hooks)*

Comment: I tried to achieve that in a generic way, to use in my projects, so I wrote this tool: https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git/

Answer (score 4):

Use [git-hooks](https://github.com/git-hooks/git-hooks). It routes `.git/hooks` invoke into scripts under the project directory, `githooks`.

There are also a lot of features to enable you to minimize copy and symlink hook all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

We are using Visual Studio solutions (and thus projects) which have pre and post build events. I'm adding an additional project named 'GitHookDeployer'. The project self modifies a file in the post build event. That file is set to copy to the build directory. Thus the project is build every time and is never skipped. In the build event, it also makes sure that all git hooks are in place.

Note that this is not a general solution, as some projects, of course, have nothing to build.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a managed solution for pre-commit hook management like [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/).
Or a centralized solution for server-side git-hooks like [Datree.io](https://datree.io/solutions/devops-policy/).
It has built-in policies like:

1. Detect and prevent [merging of secrets](https://docs.datree.io/docs/do-not-include-secret-files).
2. Enforce proper [Git user configuration](https://docs.datree.io/docs/unverified-users).
3. Enforce [Jira ticket integration](https://docs.datree.io/docs/link-pull-request-to-a-jira-ticket) - mention ticket number in pull request name / commit message.

It won't replace all of your hooks, but it might help your developers with the most obvious ones without the configuration hell of installing the hooks on every 
developers computer/repo.

Disclaimer: I am one of Datrees founders

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, hooks are written in Bash, if you follow the sample files. But you can write it in any language available, and just make sure it has the executable flag.

So, you can write a Python or Go code to achieve your goals, and place it under the hooks folder. It will work, but it will not be managed along with the repository.

**Two Options**

**a) Multi Scripts**

You can code your hooks inside your help, and add a small fragment of code to hooks, to call your perfect script, like this:

```sh
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/bin/bash
../../hooks/myprecommit.js
```

**b) Single Script**

A cooler option is to add just one script to rule them all, instead of several ones. So, you create a *hooks/mysuperhook.go* file and point every hook you want to have to it.

```sh
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/bin/bash
../../hooks/mysuperhook.go $(basename $0)
```

The parameter will provide your script which hook was triggered, and you can differentiate it inside your code. Why? Sometimes you might want to run the same check for commit and push, for instance.

**And then?**

Then, you might want to have further functionalities, like:

- Trigger the hook manually to check if everything is OK even prior to a commit or push. If you just call your script (option a or b) would do the trick.
- Trigger the hooks on [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), so you don't need to rewrite the same checks for CI. It would be just calling the commit and push triggers, for instance. The same as the above should solve it.
- Call external tools, like a markdown validator, or a [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) validator. You can make syscalls and need to handle standard output and standard error.
- Make sure all developers have a simple way to install the hooks, so a nice script needs to be added to the repository to replace default hooks with the correct ones
- Have some global helpers, like a check to block commits to develop and master branches, not having to add it to every repository. You can solve it by having another repository with global scripts.

**Can this be simpler?**

Yes, there are several tools to help you manage Git hooks. Each of them is tailored to tackle the problem from a different perspective, and you might need to understand all of them to get the one that is best for you or your team. [GitHooks.com](https://githooks.com) offers a lot of reading about hooking, and several tools available today.

As of today, there are 21 projects listed there with different strategies to manage Git hooks. Some only do it for a single hook, some for a specific language, and so on.

One of those tools, written by me and offered for free as an open-source project, is called [hooks4git](https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git). It is written in Python (because I like it), but the idea is to handle all items listed above in a single configuration file called *.hooks4git.ini*, which lives inside your repository and can call any script you want to call, in any language.

Using Git hooks is absolutely fantastic, but the way they are offered usually only gets people away from it.

Comment: I had post a very shorter version a while ago, and as agreed with moderators, this brings explanation inside it, and a brief link to a tool I wrote myself which I think may help other developers.

Answer (score 2):

### For Gradle users

I found [these scripts](https://gist.github.com/KenVanHoeylandt/c7a928426bce83ffab400ab1fd99054a) very useful for Gradle projects.

#### build.gradle

`apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/install-git-hooks.gradle')`

#### gradle/install-git-hooks.gradle

```
tasks.create(name: 'gitExecutableHooks') {
    doLast {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R +x .git/hooks/");
    }
}
task installGitHooks(type: Copy) {
    from new File(rootProject.rootDir, 'pre-commit')
    into { new File(rootProject.rootDir, '.git/hooks') }
}
gitExecutableHooks.dependsOn installGitHooks
clean.dependsOn gitExecutableHooks
```

#### pre-commit

```
.... your pre commit scripts goes here
```

Comment: File is not copying from custom directory to **.git/hooks** directory. Along with the above code, if we add this line of code it will work seemlessly.
    `fileMode 0777`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by a3765910's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294145/1438339) for Gradle but modified to run every build.

Add the following to your app's build.gradle (assuming you already created the githooks/pre-commit file you want to keep in source control):

```
copy {
    from new File(rootProject.rootDir, 'githooks/pre-commit')
    into { new File(rootProject.rootDir, '.git/hooks') }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your *hooks* folder another Git repository and link it as a submodule...

I guess it is worth it only if you have a lot of members and hooks changed regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on this in our codebase and I came across a library called `husky` which simplifies how to use and share GitHub Hooks across your team. I highly recommend looking into that.

Comment: tat is java script specific. Looks like the OP wants a generic solution to it

Comment: Apologies, I unknowingly downvoted, my bad.  I removed that. No need of sarcasm here. I was actually trying to develop something of a similar sort. We  tried Husky, I wanted this to happen in Java/ Python without the need to install a npm module. How would you justify the usage of husky in a pure Java project.? I wanted a pre commit hook.. Kind of needed to be on the client side. Do I still ask the person to first install npm  followed by husky? or have my master repo polluted with a package.json configuration ? The recent change in husky also means u have to install husky via npm right ?

Comment: @vijayakumarpsg587 thank you for removing downvote. I'm not familiar with java/python. You should be able to use GitHub Hooks without the Husky package, it just makes utilizing hooks easier.

Answer (score -1):

To version your hooks directory (assuming it's stored in `hooks/`), create a `.gitconfig` file at the working copy root with the following contents:

```
[core]
hooksPath = hooks
```

It will override `.git/config`.

Comment: the solution doesn't work. a working sample would certainly help!