# writing a post commit hook to push to my staging site, but don't think it is running for some reason

Tags: git

I have the following setup for my post commit hook:

in .git/hooks/push-to-staging

```
#!/bin/sh

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
  branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
  git push -f myapp $branch:master && heroku run rake db:migrate -a my-app && heroku restart -a my-app
done
```

I made sure to chmod +x push-to-staging.

However, when I push to any of my branches, the push goes fine obviously ... but that's it. I don't see the push to my staging server happening.

Secondly, I'm wondering if there is a way to make this post commit hook a part of my repo (or is that not how hooks are supposed to work?). I just want everyone on my team to have this setup basically.

Comment: `push-to-staging` is not a valid `git` hook name. If you want it to be run as a post commit hook, then it needs to be named `post-commit`. Also, it does not receive any input, so you'll need to use other `git` commands to collect `oldrev`, `newrev`, and `refname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such hook in Git: `push-to-staging`. You can see the available hooks in the `hooks` directory of your repository, for example in my system I have:

```
applypatch-msg
commit-msg
post-commit
post-receive
post-update
pre-applypatch
pre-commit
prepare-commit-msg
pre-rebase
update
```

In your case you are looking for the `post-commit` hook. Either rename the script to `post-commit`, or create a symlink from `post-commit` pointing to your script.

You cannot make hooks part of the repository, that is, you cannot have hooks enabled automatically and propagated through branch operations. If that was possible it would be a huge security risk when cloning a repository. What you can do instead is make it easy to enable hook scripts, you can see examples of that in these other answers:

[Putting git hooks into repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository)

[Tracking changes to hooks in .git/hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457031/tracking-changes-to-hooks-in-git-hooks)