# Git Hooks: check in or add git hooks directory to remote

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-bash

I have a local git hook (pre-commit) that  I would like to deploy for the other members of my team. The future expectation is for anyone to be able to update the hook. Is it possible  as from my understanding git hooks are local. Any advice would be great.

We are using Tortoise GIT / Git bash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking changes to hooks in .git/hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457031/tracking-changes-to-hooks-in-git-hooks)

Comment: alternatively [Putting git hooks into repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository)