# How create/add hook functions to git repository?

Tags: git, hook

I tried add ***post-commit*** function to ***.git/hook*** repository in server site.

But when I clone repository post-commit not appear in ***..clonefolder/.git/hooks*** repository.

May be this functions need to be register via cmd?

Can somebody help how rightly create/add new hook functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks are not versioned with a repo, and will not get cloned.

You can put the files somewhere in your base repo directory, and put symlinks from .git/hook to these files, but you will need to execute this setup step each time a new clone is made.

You may want to symlink the whole .git/hook directory, as suggested by several other answers :

- [Can git hooks scripts be managed along withe the repository ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)
- [Tracking changes to hooks in .git/hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457031/tracking-changes-to-hooks-in-git-hooks)
- [Git hooks management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050450/git-hooks-management)

for example