# Display warning message after commit

Tags: git

I want to display a warning message after someone commits a change.

```
$ git commit -am "First commit"  # Or `git commit -a` and then type a message in the editor
Please, don't forget to update the production repository
```

The only restriction that I have is that it can't be done to all Git repositories, it has to work only in specific directories.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `post-commit` hook.  The [documentation for that hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit) says:

> **post-commit**
>
> This hook is invoked by git commit. It takes no parameter, and is invoked after a commit is made.  This hook is meant primarily for notification, and cannot affect the outcome of git commit.

... so you can just install a post-commit hook that echos your message you mention.  How you get your users to install this hook is a different matter, covered in other answers on Stack Overflow, e.g. [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)....