# Why is .git/hooks sometimes missing in cloned repos?

Tags: git, githooks, atlassian-sourcetree

I have several (Git for Windows 2.6.2 64-bit) repos that I created and started using *the same way*:

1. Run `git init --bare <repoName>.git` in Git Bash.
2. Clone the new repo using SourceTree.
3. Add and commit initial files (through SourceTree or EGit).
4. Blah, blah, blah....

In trying to add a common `post-commit` hook to these cloned repos, I noticed that *only some of them had a `.git/hooks` directory*.  Why?

I dug for questions/answers regarding missing `.git/hook` directories and did not find anything on SO or more broadly.  Git documentation [mentions](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that repo initialization ensures the (`.git/hooks/`) `.sample` files are executable by default; but I really could not find anything that seemed to explain why my cloned repos sometimes contain `.git/hooks` and sometimes do not.

Can anyone shed some light on the cause and effect at play here?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an explanation for this? I just ran into this issue. .git/hooks was missing when cloning a repository from a Bitbucket server. I wonder if it is a SourceTree defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this a few years later.

This does seem like a SourceTree thing (as theorized by Jason above). More specifically if one uses the `Embedded Git` from SourceTree. If I use `System Git` (I'm on a Mac), then the `hooks` directory is created and populated with samples. Cloning via command-line yields the same result. When using the `Embedded Git`, then there is no `hooks` directory.

Screenshot from the `git` options in Preferences where you can select between the two.

[image]

Comment: You just made my life easy

Answer (score 9):

The defined hooks in a git repository are always local to this repository. They are no part of the git history and are not transferred when cloning, fetching or pushing.

Thus, just by cloning an existing repo with hooks, the clones repo will have none of the upstream hooks. You would have to add them manually to the cloned repository.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427207/421705) explains some options to help you achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; and the question you referenced explains further very well too.  What I still wonder then is where the `.git/hooks` directories in some of the clones came from, why `.git/hooks`' presence/absence would not be uniform across the clones if I have followed the same process to create and start using each clone.

Answer (score 1):

As git hooks are not transferred while cloning, etc. thus a lot of times the hooks are defined in a separate directory (outside of .git directory which is not cloned or transferred).

This is mostly the case with team projects and open source repos. Thus they may have some scripts (for example in their `Makefile`) which is removing the local `.git/hooks` and adding some other directory containing the hooks (for example `.githooks` in root of repo).

This is possible because you can easily configure git to set the `core.hooksPath` configuration variable to your managed hooks directory for example:
`git config core.hooksPath .githooks`