# git hooks folder is missing when cloning repository with source tree

Tags: git

I have tried to clone a git repository with sourceTree and when doing so, the hooks folder is missing in .git folder. when doing the clone from sourceTree terminal, hooks folder is not missing.

this is a different issue from [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

can anyone know how to fix this??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

Comment: please read case before answering. the is not the same issue. thank