# How to ensure `submodule update` automatically with `git pull` on a repository level

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, githooks

I have a git repository which is used across a team of 10+ developers. I have a few `git submodule`s added into my repository. The submodules can of course be checked out by the following command.

`git submodule update --init`

But if I want that the `submodule update` to happen automatically when someone does a `git pull`, is it feasible? How can I do this?

Is there something I can do with git hooks ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `update` once after cloning the project (unless you're adding new submodules). If you want to get all changes from each of the submodules like you would with `pull`, you can use the following command:

```
git pull && git submodule foreach git pull
```

This will pull on the main repository, then pull on each submodule associated with the main repository.

Or, you can set up an alias in your `.bashrc` file to do this automatically. For example, I have:

```
alias git-pull='git pull && git submodule foreach git pull'
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something once at the repository level to make this work for all developers ?

Comment: the answer you provided works local to my machine. but I am looking for something at repository level. may be something with git-hooks ?

Comment: You could share the `.bashrc` file. Server-side Git hooks will only work with the `push` action: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#server-side-hooks. Or you can manage client-side hooks as explained in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository.