# How to version a git client hook?

Tags: git

I want to make so that, every time a developer for my project makes a pull, a maven version update command is executed.
For this I know that the post_merge git hook is fine, as every pull involves a merge.

Problem is that client hooks reside on local PC: is there a way to ship a project along with a specific git hook?

Comment: Maybe something to add to maven like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836112/commit-git-hook-to-repo

Comment: I use “husky”. I wonder if that can help?