# Merge SQLite file in git hooks

Tags: git, sqlite, git-merge, githooks

I have a git repo that has a single `.sqlite` file.

It's a special DB in that it only ever has new values added; nothing is ever changed or removed. But it is possible that two branches will have the same data entered (same primary key, same values). I have code written, `merge_db.py`, that will merge two versions of that database into one.

What I'm looking for is a foolproof way to automatically merge these on a `git pull` or `git merge` action.

Are git hooks, like a pre-merge hook appropriate for this? If so, it appears this hook does not get copied with a `git clone`. Is there a way to pull it down with a `git clone`? Again, I'm looking to make it foolproof so that each user can simply clone the repo and use it with `commit`, `push`, `pull`.

Note: I'm not using a proper multi-user database like Postgres because I need it to be duplicated for each user, and available offline.

Comment: i did some more googling. i think merge-drivers are the answer. https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver

Comment: About hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+clone

Comment: Git's merge detection algorithm is intended to be run on text, not binary files.