# Git pre-commit hook not working as expected

Tags: git, githooks

I have configured my repo to use a `hooks` directory instead of the `.git/hooks` directory so that it can be [managed from within the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37861972/452281)

I want to run `sed` to redact a password before a commit occurs. I am using this code in my `hooks/pre-commit` script which I have also made executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

FNAME=smbclient.conf
sed -i -e 's/password=.*/password=See_Thycotic/g' ${FNAME}

grep -c See_Thycotic ${FNAME}
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ] ; then
    echo Failed to redact password in ${FNAME}
    exit 1
fi
echo Password was redacted in ${FNAME} before commit
```

When I run this command:

```
git commit smbclient.conf -m "changed something"
```

I see this message (as expected):

```
1
Password was redacted in smbclient.conf before commit
```

The problem is that the file is committed before the contents are changed by the `pre-commit` script.  If I then run `git status`, it tells me `modified: smbclient.conf`.

**1) How can I change this file before the commit occurs and then also have it committed?**

**2) Is it possible to have the pre-commit script run when committing only the smbclient.conf file and no other files?**

Comment: From the attached `pre-commit` hook, it seems like you forgot to run `git add` on the updated file?

Comment: @Alderath: it has already been added and previously committed. I just need to run `sed` on the file before the commit occurs.

Comment: Even if `git add` has been executed before `git commit` you also need to `git add` the updates which were made by `sed` inside the `pre-commit` hook.

Answer (score 1):

**1)**
You should let the `pre-commit` hook do `git add $FNAME` if the `$FNAME` file was updated by `sed`.

**2)**
No. It is not possible to define pre-commit hooks which will only execute for a specific file.

The proper way to do this would probably be to let the script run on every commit, but let it start by doing something along the lines of:

```bash
    if [[ "$(git diff --name-only --staged -- $FNAME)" == "" ]] #If $FNAME file is not updated in this commit
    then
        exit 0 #Stop execution of this hook, and consider hook execution successful
    fi

    #Rest of pre-commit hook script here
```