# How can I automatically synchronize a post-receive file within my project with the post-receive file in the git hook directory when I push my repo?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have a post-receive hook file that I created which I stored within my project so I can easily set it up on new servers, but I also want it to automatically replace an older version of the hook file whenever I push an updated version of it to live master.

My project file structure:

```
/var/www/myproject/utils/post-receive
```

and the path to the post-receive file on my ubuntu server is

```
/var/repo/myproject.git/hooks/post-receive
```

What's the easiest way to set this up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+distribute+hooks+repository