# Bitbucket Pipeline execute on schedule but only if there are changes

Tags: bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a scheduled bitbucket pipeline and I wanted to run the pipeline only when the changes are occurring then scheduled pipeline should run otherwise skip the pipeline execution.

However, there aren't always changes that require deployment. Ideally, if there have been no changes to the code base since the last deployment, the pipeline wouldn't run that day.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a Conditional Step with `"changesets"` and `"includePaths"` into your `yml` file.

See here for an example and a reference link (item 4 in the answer): [prevent the bitbucket pipline from tirggering when bitbucket-pipelines.yml is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648730/prevent-the-bitbucket-pipline-from-tirggering-when-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-is-up)

Answer (score 0):

The changesets won't help you out, as they always look at the last commit.
Example: You have a weekly schedule. About 3 weeks ago, you pushed a commit with changes, and there have been no commits after that. The schedule will trigger again, and the changeset will look at the last commit, which is the commit of 3 weeks ago, and will still see changes, and deploy again. even though those same changes have already been deployed last week and the week before that...