# How to pass git hook script to remote repository and to my team mates

Tags: git, azure-devops, githooks

I am team of 4 members, we have have git repo in azure devOps, I am given task to add git  hook(scan code for indentation, unwanted spaces etc). I know git hook must be added to ./.git/hooks, I have scripts ready. But how do I ensure my other teammates receive my script in their local repo, so code check is done before they  commit new files.

FYI, any changes made .git will remain only to local repo, but what is the easiest way that my git hook is passed onto all my team members?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/427207/7976758

Answer (score 3):

The problem with such a hook is that it is a [*client-side* hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks), which involves a deployment to all user.
This differs from a server-side hook, which is modified once, and applied for every user `git push` to said server.

In my case, I ask my users to make a symlink from their `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file to a file managed in the repository.
That way, updating that file is easy and applied automatically.

Comment: That solution is error-prone. I don't want to rely on my pal's goodwill to make side tasks such as symlink. Isn't there an alternative to it?

Comment: @RubemPacelli For a client-side hook, there will always be some instructions of some kinds to follow, if you want to activate said hook. I used that in an enterprise setting, where your "pals" are colleagues, and the instructions are directive that you *have* to follow. No error there.

Comment: Nothing can ensure that your colleagues will follow the instructions, that is the problem.

Comment: @RubemPacelli I agree with you. Except in an enterprise setting, those instructions are called orders. Your colleague will follow them. Or they will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

I commit hooks in the repository and tell my team mates that they can use them by setting the `core.hooksPath`, e.g.

```
git config core.hooksPath './hooks'
```

Here is my [example repository](https://github.com/renelink/git-tips-and-tricks) on github

Answer (score 0):

You can set up git hooks in the dependency install stage(`npm install`, `maven`, `cargo`...), and read real commands from project source code.

Have a look at [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation to @ReneLink's and @VonC's answers :

you can commit a script which sets up the hooks for any repo, and instruct the users to run it on their local clone.

For example, have a `repo-setup.sh` script with :

```
#!/bin/bash

# set the hooksPath config to point to a versioned directory :
git config core.hooksPath './hooks'

# or :
#!/bin/bash

# set a symlink for 'pre-commit' hook :
ln -nsf ../../pre-commit-hook.sh .git/hooks/pre-commit
```