# Post-receive githook does not trigger, despite having execution permissions?

Tags: git, githooks

I've seen a lot of other questions here like this one, but the vast majority of them are related to permissions. So to clarify:

- My file is called exactly "post-receive"
- It has no extension
- It is located in .git/hooks
- It starts with "#!/bin/bash"
- It has execution permissions

Running "ls -l post-receive" returns:

> -rwxr-xr-x

If I run the file manually, through git bash, it works perfectly. But no matter what I push, it never triggers automatically. What's going on here?

Comment: is that `.git/hooks/post-receive` file on the server or on your machine?  `post-receive` is a **server side** hook

Comment: @AnthonySottile How can the post-receive hook be on the server, if you can't commit githooks? .git folder is not part of the repository and that's where the githook is.

Comment: @peepeepoopoo `post-receive` is a server side hook! You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427207/7976758) store hooks in the repository but you have to have access to `.git/hooks/` at the server. If the server is a Git hosting like Github/Gitlab then you cannot have server-side hooks but you can have webhooks.

Comment: @phd Yeah, that was it. If you want you can make an answer so I can pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) is a server side hook! You can [store hooks in the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427207/7976758) but you have to have access to `.git/hooks/` at the server. If the server is a Git hosting like Github/Gitlab then you cannot have server-side hooks but you can have [webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks).